# Calculating the length of curve using dyadic partition

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function.  The length of $\gamma$ is usually defined as

$$\sup_{0 = t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n = 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i+1})) \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\},$$

where the supremum is taken over all partitions of $[0,1]$.

Question: can we restrict ourselves to the partitions of $[0,1]$ coming from the dyadic rationals?  More precisely, for $k \geq 1$ define

$$\ell_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\gamma(\frac{i}{2^k}),\gamma(\frac{i+1}{2^k})).$$

It is clear that the $\ell_k$ are non-decreasing in $k$.  Then is it true that $\lim_{k \mapsto \infty} \ell_k$ equals the length of $\gamma$?  This limit is less than or equal to the length of $\gamma$, but it's not clear to me how to prove the opposite inequality.

Comment: Take an arbitrary partition, fix it, and use the continuity to show that the sum doesn't change too much if we approximate each partition point by a close enough dyadic rational. Adding more dyadic points after that only increases the sum. Voting to close.

Comment: Incidentally, the answer is negative in general for $\gamma$ of bounded variation and discontinuous.

Comment: For a reference, see e.g. Cours d'analyse (tome 2)  by Gustave Choquet.